# .NET Framework 1.0. Как под него писать? Совместим ли он с новыми версиями?

Tags: c#, framework

Добрый день.

Есть потребность писать под .NET Framework 1.0, т.к. он по дефолту стоит в 2003\XP. Но он отсутствует в моей VS.

1. Как под него вообще писать? Где можно найти инфу?
2. Совместим ли он с новыми версиями дотнета? Т.е. будет ли софт работать в Vista и выше?

P.S. Если есть те, кто писал под 1.0, прошу поделиться опытом. В какой VS писали, нюансы и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я советую писать в таком случае под .NET 2.0. По дефолту в XP никакой .NET не стоит. Вот пруфлинк - https://clck.ru/9ShnB

При этом .NET хотя бы версии 2.0 реально стоит практически на каждой ХР-машине.

Если нужна прям стопроцентная гарантия, то даже не знаю... Может, на VB 6.0 писать?

Comment: Хотелось бы вникнуть именно в 1.0

Comment: >Хотелось бы вникнуть именно в 1.0

зачем вам это? Это кусок дерь..пардон..кода, который давным-давно никем не поддерживается и никому не нужен

Comment: @DreamChild, хотябы лоадер\инсталлер дотнета 2.0 сделать.

Comment: Я не знаю, какова специфика Ваших задач, но очень сомневаюсь, что .NET является обязательным компонентом. Об этом косвенно говорит тот факт, что Вы были готовы даже на даунгрейд до .NET 1.0. Если нужен язык со сборкой мусора и удобными структурами данных, можно рассмотреть и другие варианты, начиная с Go и вплоть до Lua, начиная с Julia и вплоть до Euphoria. Это самый лучший способ избежать всех этих проблем с версиями дотнета. Если же позарез нужен именно дотнет, то вот - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framewor

Comment: >хотябы лоадер\инсталлер дотнета 2.0 сделать.

я, может, чего-то не понимаю, но зачем все это? Вы готовы отказаться от минимальной поддерживаемой и вменяемой версии .NET только ради установщика? Да плюньте на это и выдавайте пользователю предупреждение, что, дескать, чувак, если хочешь запустить мою программу, то скачай фреймворк хотя бы из средневековья, а не из каменного века.

Comment: Я знаю человека, который пишет на C# 3.0 под .NET 3.5 и объясняет это так: чтобы программа работала на Windows 7 без лишних телодвижений. Согласитесь, похожая мотивация. Но ориентироваться на Windows XP сейчас? Она мало у кого уже стоит, а если все еще стоит, то на нее всегда можно поставить .NET 3.x/4.0. И обычно он уже установлен. То есть мы имеем дело с классическим соотношением 80/20. Если мы будем ориентироваться на XP, то получим 80% проблем из-за 20% пользователей. Если будем ориентироваться на Windows 7, то лишим себя 80% проблем и останемся с 80% пользователей (на самом деле - с 95%)